# R forcing arguments to pass to sub-function

Tags: r, function, arguments

Generally speaking, I have some function `foo(x,...)` where `...` is passed to some other sub-function that also contains the argument `x`. When I call `foo(x=somestuff,...)` , `somestuff` will be passed to `foo()` and not the sub-function. I want to force `x` to be passed to the sub-function. E.g. I would like to do something like `foo(x=NA,subfunc.x=somestuff,...)`.

Concrete example:

The packages Network and sna contain the functions `network.arrow()` and `gplot.arrow()` respectively. Both of these functions accept the argument `col`, but they also pass arguments to `polygon()` which also accepts the argument `col`. Supposing I would like to pass `col` to `polygon()`, (in this case to change the color of the arrow shaft) how would I get these functions to do that?

Edit: I don't want the main function to use the argument I am passing to the sub-function.

Comment: To clarify, you want to pass the argument to the subfunction without the primary function using it? In your example, you want polygon()'s color to change but not network.arrow() or plot.arrow()s colors to change?

Comment: Doesn't seem as though it should be too hard to make this question more concrete. I'm still not able to get the intent from the uncoded description.